# Apache lucene delete not working

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am very new to Apache lucene and I am trying to build an index using 4.7.0. 
I am able to index the documents (which are Arabic documents) just fine, however I am having issues with deleting documents. The code I am using to delete documents is as follows.

```
public void deleteFile(String filePath) {
    System.out.println("Reached at deleting a file" );
    try {
        Term term = new Term("path", filePath);
        writer.deleteDocuments(term);
        writer.commit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() + "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Where "path" is a field  that saves the path of the file in the corpus folder.

Below is how I have indexed the path field

```
doc.add(new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
```

when I try deleting any of the documents I indexed using the above method, it doesn't work and I am still able to see the deleted document still part of the index by using Luke.Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did. It still shows the deleted documents. @femtoRgon

Comment: Appreciating your help @femtoRgon ...but yes, i did try that and i am sure that filepath string I sent is the same as that is indexed by the path field. If you know of any good or reliable examples of creating indexes and deleting documents from index, Could you please give me their links?

Comment: All right, I'm curious on this one.  Here's a quick, runnable example (using Lucene 4.7), using the code you've provided: http://pastebin.com/Bb9yWF23 .  Seems to be working, so it doesn't look like the issue is really in that code, per se.  If you can modify this simple example such that it reproduces your issue, then we should be able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [forceMergeDeletes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#forceMergeDeletes()) solves the problem. You must use it after calling deleteDocuments.